# As soon as I stack more than 3 cubes, they start to bounce and slide. How can I fix this?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

I am currently building a simple mixed reality application in Unity where you should be able to stack different sized cubes on top of each other. As soon as I add a third cube though, the collision seems to get weird. I have already played around with the rigidbody settings but so far nothing has worked. I have also enabled adaptive force.

[image: As soon as I add a third cube, they "slide into each other"]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to freeze the x and z axis on the rigidbody